# ImportError: No module named app.models

Tags: python, django, importerror, file-not-found

I'm learning Django and I keep bumping into obstacles and it takes time googling to overcome the hurdle. But this one took me over 20 minutes and I still don't know the answer.

I know this is simple but I tried many things and can't seem to get access to my models.py. I keep getting the same error

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "import_states.py", line 11, in 
>   from app.models import State
>   ImportError: No module named app.models

**Code in Context**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("..")

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

from app.models import State

states = State.objects.all()

for state in states:
    print state.name
```

Here is the **path to my script folder that contains the script**

```
/Users/ahmedawayhan/Development/projects/states/project/scripts
```

and here is the **path to the folder that contains the models.py**

```
/Users/ahmedawayhan/Development/projects/states/app
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with django - but if I remember correctly, calling `import app.models` will look for a folder `app` in the script's directory. Since that isn't the case, it fails.

Comment: Can you confirm that there's a `__init__.py` in your `states/app/` directory ?

Comment: yes there is a '__init__.py' and when i run script using ./manage.py shell, I can import from app.models and it works.

Comment: "I'm learning Django and I keep bumping into obstacles and it takes time googling to overcome the hurdle." - That's part of programming :)

Comment: @AhmadAbdullahAwayhan, shouldnt django apps be run from that shell all the time anyways? How are you running the script instead? from a CLI python interpreter? IDE?

Comment: I'm doing "Python import_states.py" when I'm in the scripts folder. is that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in ths way. Do it in the django-way. First read about [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/)

And add:

**app/management/commands/import_states.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from app.models import State

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

    states = State.objects.all()

    for state in states:
        print state.name
```

and call it:

```
python manage.py import_states
```

If You really need Your-way:

```
sys.path.append("../..")
```

or call:

```
python project/scripts/import_states.py
```